# How to model hike path in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

I want to create the database in neo4j using gpx files. 
I Can easily extract the data in 3D (lat, lon, elev) from gpx file, but I do not know how to model it in neo4j using spatial functions. 
Then when I finish with the database, I want to be able to browse those hikes, search through them etc.

I can create a node with:

```
CREATE (n:hike { name: 'hike1', p1: point({x: 56.7, y: 12.78, z: 8.0}), p2: point({x: 56.7, y: 12.78, z: 8.0}) })
```

But then, will it be correctly stored in R-tree spatial structure which is inbuilt in neo ?

How do Can i achieve that ?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. You already know how to model a hike, it seems. Why do you care if neo4j internally use R-Trees?

Comment: @cybersam Because I assuming that search queries will be faster. Am I right ?

Comment: I don't know. You could try to benchmarking the speed if your use case really requires the fastest performance.